# C# / vb.net winforms app cannot communicate with SQL server when client is running a VPN (such as NordVPN, TunnelBear)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a winforms app that communicates perfectly with the SQL server until the user is using a VPN (such as NordVPN, TunnelBear) to hide their public IP address.

The exception is "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible."

I have tried to edit the SQL connection string to use the IP address instead of the SQL server name, but that did not seem to help.

Comment: In no way familiar with your personal circumstances, but, a previous companies IT Security policy was that when their VPN was active, all network traffic was routed down the VPN (and local services such as printers and databases were no longer available). I suggest looking through VPN config to see if it has anything similar

Comment: What do you expect? As long as the SQL server is not reachable within the VPN, what is your app supposed to do? You have to either store your data locally or the user has to fix his routing tables.

Comment: Do these VPNs allow port 1433? Is the server open to the IPs that these VPNs use for outbound traffic? I'm assuming the server isn't on your LAN.

Comment: It may also be worth looking in to connecting to the SQL Server using Named Pipes if the TCP connections fail.

Comment: Thank you guys... I forgot to mention that the database is hosted on Azure, and it is using port 1433, like this: myserver.database.windows.net,1433.  The server is open to all IP's.  Is it possible to use a Named Pipe with Azure?  If so, that might be my best bet.

Comment: If the database address is `myserver.database.windows.net` and its security configuration allows the IP address you have when accessing via the VPN to connect, then you should contact the VPN provider to ask why the traffic isn't getting through.

Comment: Great point John, thank you, that makes sense to me.  Actually, one of the VPN's that I was testing mysteriously started working out of the blue... so I think you are right.